# How to install EF 4.3?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Right now I am using EF 4.1. I want to upgrade to 4.3. What I did is:
1. Install NuGet for VS 2010
2. Use Manage NuGet Packages to install EF 4.3.

then then I got error message said:
The item C:\MyFolder\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

Quite confused by this message, because MyFolder should not be involved for this install as it is user created folder. Does it mean I should install something before running Manage NuGet Packages to install EF 4.3?

Comment: "MyFolder should not be involved for this install"

Is your solution inside "C:\MyFolder" ? 
When NuGet installs a package, it creates a "packages" folder in the solution folder to install/extract the packages. Then references are added to your project pointing to the libraries in that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Figured it out and resolved.